# Robot framework Selenium: How to disable popup blocking in firefox?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, robotframework, popupwindow

I try to disable popup blocking in Robot Framework for Firefox in different ways: by setting preference dom.disable_beforeunload=False, setting capabilities and profile. It does not work. Pop up confirmation windows are not shown. See Open Firefox browser keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Firefox browser 
   ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].FirefoxOptions()    sys   
   Call Method    ${options}   set_preference    dom.disable_beforeunload  False
   Call Method    ${options}   set_capability    unhandledPromptBehavior  ignore
   Call Method    ${options}   set_capability    unexpectedAlertBehaviour  ignore

   ${profile}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].FirefoxProfile()    sys   
   Call Method    ${profile}   set_preference    dom.disable_beforeunload  False

   ${desired_capabilities}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX    sys   
   Set To Dictionary   ${desired_capabilities}  unhandledPromptBehavior  ignore 
   Set To Dictionary   ${desired_capabilities}  unexpectedAlertBehaviour  ignore 

   Open Browser  ${LOGIN_URL}  Firefox    options=${options}  ff_profile_dir=${profile}  desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}
```

For Chrome there is no such a problem. Everything works by adding the argument --disable-popup-blocking.

```
Open Chrome browser 
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys   
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --disable-popup-blocking
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN_URL}    Chrome    options=${options}
```